# Adding up inputs into an array and creating a sum

Tags: javascript, arrays

So my problem is I have multiple inputs that I'm trying to add up all the numbers from them up.

The values go into an array but I need to take that array and create the sum.

Also I have triggering the function onchange so that way the sum updates.

Here's currently what I have: https://codepen.io/DilionsCode/pen/vYGEXOm

```
var sum;
function Geeks() {
  var input = document.getElementsByName("fields[]");
  // ForLoop
  input.forEach(Add);
}
function Add(item, index) {
   var sum = sum + item;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not redeclare the variable `sum` inside the function and instead increment the global variable. Furthermore, you should be summing the `value`s of the select elements.

```
function Add(item, index) {
  sum = sum + Number(item.value);
}
```

Live Example:

```js
var sum;
function Geeks() {
  var input = document.getElementsByName("fields[]");
  // ForLoop
  sum = 0;
  input.forEach(Add);
  document.querySelector('#score').textContent = "Score: " + sum;
}
function Add(item, index) {
   sum = sum + Number(item.value);
}
```

```html
<select name="fields[]" onchange="Geeks()">
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
</select>
<select name="fields[]" onchange="Geeks()">
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
</select>
<p id="score">Score: 2</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Updating the state of the global variable is not considered as the best practice.

```
function Geeks() {
  var input = document.getElementsByName("fields[]");
  let sum = 0;
  // ForLoop
  input.forEach((index, item) => {
   sum = sum + Number(item.value);
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Iterate with forEach through the input-fields and sum the values. parseInt is necessary because the values are strings.

```js
function Geeks() {
  let input = document.getElementsByName("fields[]");
  let sum = 0;
  input.forEach(elem =>  sum += parseInt(elem.value));
  document.getElementById('score').innerHTML = 'Score: ' + sum;
}

// Initialize sum at start
Geeks();
```

```html
<select name="fields[]" onchange="Geeks()">
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
</select>
<select name="fields[]" onchange="Geeks()">
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
</select>
<p id="score">Score:</p>
```